# Laravel 5.1 date_format validation allow two formats

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, date-format

I use following date validation for incoming POST request.

```
'trep_txn_date' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u"'
```

This will only allow a date of this kind i.e. 2012-01-21 15:59:44.8

I also want to allow date without the TIME e.g. 2012-01-21, which when sent to mysql db will automatically store as 2012-01-21 00:00:00.0

Is there a way I can do this using a Laravel's existing validation rules.
Is there a way to define multiple formats in date_format rule something like below.

```
'trep_txn_date' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u","Y-m-d"' //btw this didn't work.
```

Thanks,

K

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The **date_format** validator takes only one date format as parameter. In order to be able to use multiple formats, you'll need to build a custom validation rule. Luckily, it's pretty simple.

You can define the multi-format date validation in your **AppServiceProvider** with the following code:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('date_multi_format', function($attribute, $value, $formats) {
      // iterate through all formats
      foreach($formats as $format) {

        // parse date with current format
        $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);

        // if value matches given format return true=validation succeeded 
        if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      // value did not match any of the provided formats, so return false=validation failed
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

You can later use this new validation rule like that:

```
'trep_txn_date' => 'date_multi_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u","Y-m-d"'
```

You can read more about how to create custom validation rules here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Yes I was thinking of a custom validation rule, but the way you showed is indeed nice way to deal with it. Thanks.

Comment: The issue here is that date_format allows to work after and before rules with that format, after and before will not work properly here

Comment: Anybody seeing this in 2020, use this for custom validation rule. It's much more cleaner. Keeps Authserviceprovider cleaner.  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 4):

The approved answer from jedrzej.kurylo is outdated as the `date_format` rule provided by Laravel itself can take multiple formats by now. The implementation is basically the same as given by jedrzej.kurylo:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v9.25.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L495-L512

(Answer as I do not have enough reputation to comment yet.)

Comment: That's very interesting. I notice that `validateDateFormat()` changed in `8.x`, if I am not mistaken. I think @jedrzej.kurylo's answer is still valid because the question definitely refers to Laravel 5.1. But your link to github is very interesting and useful. Maybe a note at the start of your answer to mention when the `date_format` rule changed would be useful too.