# Laravel Eloquent date_format Validation fails on given format

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent

I want to create validation rule to validate incoming date.
Format I want to validate is Y-m-d H:i:s. Here's my body request which I am validating:

```
{ "date":"2015.10.5 10:30:10" }
```

And here's my validation rule:

```
'date' => 'required|date_format:"Y.m.d H:i:s"',
```

And it returns:

> {"date":["The date does not match the format Y.m.d H:i:s."]}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass the day **without** a leading zero, then for the day part of your datetime you need to use `j` instead of `d`.

```
'date' => 'required|date_format:"Y.m.j H:i:s"',
```

That will work for the example you have above.

If you are going to always have a leading zero in your day (so, `05` instead of just `5`, then the date format you already have will work.

Comment: Does j works for both cases leading zeros and non leading?

Comment: No. You'll need to either decide which format you'll enforce, or extend the `Validator` with your own rule like what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32006537/1177191. You can probably also use a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules) (L5.5)