# L5.6 - Validate multiple 'rules' in OR

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.6

I need to validate an input date param, called `starttime`, that could be passed in two format `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` or `Y-m-d`.

Now, my PHP code validate only one rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input_data, [
    'starttime'     => 'date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"',
]);
```

how I can validate `starttime` using two rules in `OR`?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134551/l5-6-validate-multiple-rules-in-or#new-answer

Comment: what error you want if none matched ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 date\_format validation allow two formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006092/laravel-5-1-date-format-validation-allow-two-formats)

Comment: Yes, the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006092/laravel-5-1-date-format-validation-allow-two-formats could be a solution. I'll try on L5.6. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, using the [Rule Objects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules):

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class StartOrEndDateRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $return1 = true;
        $return2 = true;

        /* Check validation on 'YYYY-MM-DD\THH:ii:ss' */
        $validator = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], [
            $attribute      => 'date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $return1 = false;
        }

        /* Check validation on 'YYYY-MM-DD' */
        $validator = Validator::make([$attribute => $value], [
            $attribute      => 'date_format:"Y-m-d"',
        ]);     
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $return2 = false;
        }

        /* Check value to return */
        if ( $return1 === false && $return2 === false ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The ":attribute" does not match the format "Y-m-d\TH:i:s" or "Y-m-d"';
    }
}
```

and in the Controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input_data, [
    'starttime'     => [new StartOrEndDateRule],
]);
```