# How to validate date time with many format in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I want to check my request datetime with many format look like below format:

```
Y-m-d
Y-m-
Y-m
```

In Laravel, I use Validator to validate datetime, but Validator can not make checking with many format. This is my code:

```
Validator::make(['date' => $departureDate], [
   'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d, Y-m, Y-m-'
]);
```

How can I do it in laravel
Please help me! Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 date\_format validation allow two formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006092/laravel-5-1-date-format-validation-allow-two-formats)

Comment: For anyone coming here looking for current laravel version answers its now supported by default.  For example `'start_at' => ['date_format:"m/d/Y g:i A", "Y-m-d\TH:i"', 'nullable'],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write a custom validation format for that. Laravel's date_format expects only one parameter and not capable of handling multi-formats. There are Two ways to add custom validation. first, one is making a rule repository and add your validation logic there. [Here](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/custom-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-5-c6cb250f65df) Taylor Otwell explained this method.

The other way to doing that is extend validation in app service provider and add new rule there. add this code in app service provider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


Validator::extend('multi_date_format', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters,$validator) {

    $ok = true;

    $result = [];

      // iterate through all formats
      foreach ($parameters as $parameter){

         //validate with laravels standard date format validation
         $result[] = $validator->validateDateFormat($attribute,$value,[$parameter]);
      }

    //if none of result array is true. it sets ok to false
    if(!in_array(true,$result)){
        $ok = false;
        $validator->setCustomMessages(['multi_date_format' => 'The format must be one of Y-m-d ,Y-m or Y-m-']);
    }

    return $ok;
});
```

And here you can use it this way:

```
$validator = Validator::make(['date' => '2000-02-01'], [
    'date' => 'required|multi_date_format:Y-m-d,Y-m,Y-m-'
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
    $errors = $validator->errors()->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register custom validator in file **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** in boot method.

```
Validator::extend('several_date_format', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters,$validator) {
    foreach ($parameters as $parameter){
        if (!$validator->validateDateFormat($attribute,$value,[$parameter]))
           return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Now you can use it

```
'your_date' => 'required|several_date_format:Y-m-d,...'
```

Optional after it you can add custom message in resources/lang/en/validation.php

```
return [
   ...
   'several_date_format' => 'Error text'
   ...
]
```

Comment: I saw that you miss something. What do u think about the failure case is in the first position in array $parameters