# How to validate date using different date format in Laravel using validation rule?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Actually, I want to validate date in laravel validation rules.

```
'sometimes|date_format:Y-m-d|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
```

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string|between:3,100',
            'created_at' => 'sometimes|date_format:Y-m-d|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',
            'updated_at' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'date_of_purchase' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'date_of_expiration' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d'
        ];
    }
```

Expectations

```
 'created_at' => 'sometimes|date_format:Y-m-d, Y-M-d H:i:s',
```

Is there any way to do this like above mentioned line code. Hope got that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 date\_format validation allow two formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006092/laravel-5-1-date-format-validation-allow-two-formats)

Comment: Its custom solution. I am looking for built-in one.

Comment: As the answer says there is no built-in solution since `date_format` only takes one date, so your only solution is creating a custom validation rule.

Comment: Thanks for your time.